# ASP.NET MVC message box from controller to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
private void Inserir()
    {mdc = new ModelDataContext();
try
        {
            Tbl_Controle_Procedimento procedimento = new Tbl_Controle_Procedimento();
            //dados do paciente
            procedimento.paciente = Convert.ToDecimal(TxtCns.Text.Trim());
            procedimento.nome = TxtNome.Text.Trim();
            procedimento.regiao = DrpSetor.SelectedValue;
            procedimento.complexidade = DrpComplexidade.Text;
            procedimento.colonizador_multi = DrpColonizador.Text;
            procedimento.diagnostico = DrpDiagnostico.Text;
            procedimento.cid_assossiado = TxtCidAssossiado.Text;
            mdc.Tbl_Controle_Procedimentos.InsertOnSubmit(procedimento);
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "alerta", "alert('Save records with success')", true);
}
```

I am using this statement to show the msg for the user, but this message box is not as same as Windows Message box. Can any one tell me how i can replace this with windows message box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message box is specific to browser it is not specific to operating system..you can see diffrent messagebox in differnt browser...and this messagebox are generated by browser using javascript ..

If you want to make uniform messagebox than you can make use of [jQuery-UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) ....

Tutorial : [JqueryUI - Dialog](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_dialog.htm)

Comment: Yes, I agreed with you this msgBox is generated by browser. You are suggesting me to use jquery. I think about this too but can you give me some example how to embeed this jquery in my c# or how i can use jquery at that place. Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: you can check link provided in my answer

Comment: Thanks Buddy, i just understand what i was looking for. Thanks once again for the tutorials

Comment: @AbbasZahid - no problem..no thanks for answering ...i like it that y i do it ...:)